# How to display elements in the same column?

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I want to display some tables (i don't know neither the number of tables nor their lengths). Those tables are composed by only 5 columns. Thus, I want to display all the tables into three columns on the screen (cf screenshots). 
I don't know how to make sure that the title will be in the same column as the table it is related to, I mean that a title can be at the bottom of a column and the table can be at the top of next column.

Link to the screenshot :

http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/15/1sm8.png"

The HTML :
     
            In progress

```
    {% for temp in list_of %}
        <div class="group">
        <div class="title-table round">
            {{temp.pn}}
        </div>

        <table class="table round group">

            <thead>
                <tr class="">
                    <th class="round"></th>
                    <th class="round grey">OF</th>
                    <th class="round grey">Start Date</th>
                    <th class="round grey">End date</th>
                    <th class="round grey">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {% for temp_of in temp.list_of_pn %}

            <tr class="highlight-black">
                {% if temp_of.complete == 0 %}
                <td class="round"><i class="fas fa-times-circle uncomplete round"></i></td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if temp_of.complete == 1 %}
                <td class="round"><i class="fas fa-check-circle complete round"></i></td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if temp_of.complete == None %}
                <td class="round"></td>
                {% endif %}

                <td class="round cell">
                    <a href = "{% url 'app_rafale:of_overview' pk=temp_of.pk %}" {{temp_of.num_of}}>
                        {{temp_of.num_of}}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="round cell">
                    {{temp_of.start_date |date:'d/m/Y'}}
                </td>
                <td class="round cell">
                    {{temp_of.end_date |date:'d/m/Y'}}
                </td>
                <td class="round cell">
                    {{temp_of.prod_status}}
                </td>

            </tr>

    </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 .subtitle{
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 text-align: center;
 color : #fff;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top : 1%;
 width: auto;
 font-size: 150%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }

 .global{
 background-color: rgba(187, 210, 225, .8);
 margin : 0.5%;
 padding: 10px;
 }

 .title-table{
 padding : 3px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color: #fff;
 }

 .table{
         padding: 5px;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     color: #fff;
 }


 .row-of{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

 }

 .group{
     column-span : 1;
 }

 .highlight-black:hover .cell{
 background-color: #111;
 }

 .col-2{
 position: relative;
 margin : 0.5%;
 float: left;
 width: 49%;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: rgba(187, 210, 225, .8);
 }
```

I want the titles "VP0680" and "SP0731" at the top of their related tables which are in the next column.

Comment: This isn't very easy on the eye or even user friendly, is there a reason to do it this way? Also, this seems like a problem that only exists because you've chosen to have the column headers be separate from the table, what is the reason for this? If you must keep everything as is I don't see how you can do this without some javascript or back-end logic.

Comment: There is no special reason I am just trying to have the display I want.
It is not a problem with the column headers but with the table title !

Comment: The only thing that I cannot display the way I want is :
        <div class="title-table round">
            {{temp.pn}}
        </div>

Comment: You could always have the table header be your "title-table round" and a static second row of your header columns, then populate your data beneath starting on the third rows. This will keep everything together and intact.

Comment: It is the solution I was looking for. I though that the table headers have to be the column headings... Thank you very much !

Comment: No problem, have a great day!